# Error when fetching category posts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I made simple CMS using laravel and when i try to get posts inside single category page.Using **$category->posts()** which i assigned in my category model but for some reason it's not defined and i get the following error
[image]

And here is my codes

**Category Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function posts() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Posts')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Post Model**

```
        <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Post extends Model
    {
        public function categories() 
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withTimestamps();
        }

        public function user() 
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        }

        public function meta() 
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Postmeta');
        }
    }

**Category Controller**
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Category;

class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return view('frontend.categories.index')->withCategories(Category::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(6));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $slug
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getSingle($slug)
    {
        $category   = Category::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
        $posts      = ($category !== null) ? $category->posts() : array();

        return view('frontend.categories.single')->withCategory($category)->withPosts($posts);
    }
}
```

Comment: You just have made a simply spelling mistake. Your model name is 'Post' but in your category you try to access it with 'Posts'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a typo.

You put `Posts` instead of `Post`.

`$this->belongsToMany('App\Post')`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function posts() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG this was it :D i was getting crazy to find the problem i think because i'm new to laravel plus errors are not helping to know what file causing the issue :-/

Comment: @YasserMoussa you need an good ide any normal ide will instantly told you the posts is undefined and you spot it in seconds

Comment: I agree with you @AmirBar because i am using notepadd++ thanks for the advice